# Unexplained non-Android entry in my Android app Google Analytics page

Tags: android, analytics

I recently observed the output of Google Analytics for my Android app and noticed the following strange "Macintosh Intel 10.10" entry:

[mobile app analytics chart http://transsymmetrix.com:8080/tmp/googleAnalyticsReport.png](http://transsymmetrix.com:8080/tmp/googleAnalyticsReport.png)

see the yellow segment representing 9.6% of the OS versions.
Anybody have any idea why Macintosh OS is showing up as an Android OS version ???!
Thnx in advance.

Comment: it's seem to be explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125239/i-am-tracking-my-android-app-on-google-analytics-why-do-i-appear-to-have-macint