# I am tracking my IOS app on Google Analytics, Whats Macintosh Users?

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm looking my Google Analytics reports about my IOS app, and i got IOS users and Macintosh users, the weird thing is that mostly of my users are from Macintosh.

Any idea? i thought about IOS emulators on Mac but its really wird to have 70% from there and 30% from IOS.

Any idea?

thanks!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [I am tracking my Android app on Google Analytics. Why do I appear to have Macintosh users?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125239/i-am-tracking-my-android-app-on-google-analytics-why-do-i-appear-to-have-macint)