# iOS Google Analytics incorrect numbers

Tags: android, ios, iphone, google-analytics

We have GA for both Android and iOS. Comparing with Fabric(Crashlytics) sessions, Android numbers are ok, but iOS numbers are 5-6 times bigger than they should be, and they seem highly unrealistic (92% users are on iOS, 8% on Android, which we know for fact it isn't true).

GA iOS SDK version is v3.

Code is the usual:

```
[GAI sharedInstance].trackUncaughtExceptions = YES;
[GAI sharedInstance].dispatchInterval = 20;
[[GAI sharedInstance] trackerWithTrackingId:gaTrackId];

#ifdef DEBUG
[[[GAI sharedInstance] logger] setLogLevel:kGAILogLevelVerbose];
#endif
```

Anyone knows why GA tracks users incorrectly on iOS?

Comment: Take a look at this question/answer, maybe this is the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29125239/i-am-tracking-my-android-app-on-google-analytics-why-do-i-appear-to-have-macint/